# Thin server process hanging at 100% CPU in what appears to be a regex loop. Where can I get more information to debug?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, debugging, thin

I have a gdb backtrace on it that yields this:

```
#0  match_at (reg=0xcce4a00, 
    str=0xd47b101 "206193045.1297252703.66.40.utmcsr=sendmail|utmccn=52%%20off|utmcmd=email|utmctr=View%20this|utmcct=52%%20off", end=0xd47b1a6 "", 
    sstart=0xd47b101 "206193045.1297252703.66.40.utmcsr=sendmail|utmccn=52%%20off|utmcmd=email|utmctr=View%20this|utmcct=52%%20off", 
    sprev=0xd47b131 "52%%20off|utmcmd=email|utmctr=View%20this|utmcct=52%%20off", 
    msa=0x7fff7bc66870) at regexec.c:2433
#1  0x00002b785390329c in onig_search (reg=0xcce4a00, 
    str=0xd47b101 "206193045.1297252703.66.40.utmcsr=sendmail|utmccn=52%%20off|utmcmd=email|utmctr=View%20this|utmcct=52%%20off", end=0xd47b1a6 "", start=<value optimized out>, 
    range=0xd47b102 "06193045.1297252703.66.40.utmcsr=sendmail|utmccn=52%%20off|utmcmd=email|utmctr=View%20this|utmcct=52%%20off", region=0x7fff7bc66990, option=0) at regexec.c:3646
#2  0x00002b78538ef51e in rb_reg_search (re=137570880, str=218457520, pos=0, reverse=0) at re.c:1372
#3  0x00002b78538efc42 in rb_reg_match (re=214846549, str=218457520) at re.c:2740
#4  0x00002b7853971c36 in vm_exec_core (th=0x8329020, initial=<value optimized out>) at insns.def:2089
#5  0x00002b7853979b99 in vm_exec (th=0xcce4c55) at vm.c:1147
#6  0x00002b7853970cd9 in invoke_block_from_c (th=0x8329020, block=0x2b78572fea38, self=174397400, argc=1, argv=0x0, blockptr=0x0, cref=0x0)
    at vm.c:558
#7  0x00002b785397b037 in vm_yield (val=218457520) at vm.c:588
#8  rb_yield_0 (val=218457520) at vm_eval.c:740
#9  rb_yield (val=218457520) at vm_eval.c:750
#10 0x00002b7853840926 in rb_ary_collect (ary=218457680) at array.c:2166
#11 0x00002b78539716aa in vm_call_cfunc (th=0x8329020, cfp=0x2b78572fea10, num=0, blockptr=0x2b78572fea39, flag=0, id=1544, me=0x83e0ac0, 
    recv=218457680) at vm_insnhelper.c:402
#12 vm_call_method (th=0x8329020, cfp=0x2b78572fea10, num=0, blockptr=0x2b78572fea39, flag=0, id=1544, me=0x83e0ac0, recv=218457680)
    at vm_insnhelper.c:524
#13 0x00002b785397438c in vm_exec_core (th=0x8329020, initial=<value optimized out>) at insns.def:1006
#14 0x00002b7853979b99 in vm_exec (th=0xcce4c55) at vm.c:1147
#15 0x00002b7853970cd9 in invoke_block_from_c (th=0x8329020, block=0x2b78572feb40, self=174397400, argc=1, argv=0x0, blockptr=0x0, cref=0x0)
    at vm.c:558
#16 0x00002b785397b037 in vm_yield (val=218460560) at vm.c:588
#17 rb_yield_0 (val=218460560) at vm_eval.c:740
#18 rb_yield (val=218460560) at vm_eval.c:750
#19 0x00002b785383bc9c in rb_ary_each (ary=218460960) at array.c:1427
#20 0x00002b78539716aa in vm_call_cfunc (th=0x8329020, cfp=0x2b78572feb18, num=0, blockptr=0x2b78572feb41, flag=0, id=424, me=0x83dfb90, 
    recv=218460960) at vm_insnhelper.c:402
#21 vm_call_method (th=0x8329020, cfp=0x2b78572feb18, num=0, blockptr=0x2b78572feb41, flag=0, id=424, me=0x83dfb90, recv=218460960)
    at vm_insnhelper.c:524
#22 0x00002b785397438c in vm_exec_core (th=0x8329020, initial=<value optimized out>) at insns.def:1006
#23 0x00002b7853979b99 in vm_exec (th=0xcce4c55) at vm.c:1147
#24 0x00002b785396b4e5 in vm_call0 (th=0x8329020, recv=180469600, id=384, argc=2, argv=0x7fff7bc67990, me=0xd47b130) at vm_eval.c:66
#25 0x00002b785396d354 in vm_method_missing (th=0x8329020, id=1513486, recv=180469600, num=<value optimized out>, blockptr=0x0, opt=0)
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
    at vm_insnhelper.c:448
#26 0x00002b78539715e3 in vm_call_method (th=0x8329020, cfp=0x0, num=1, blockptr=0x0, flag=0, id=5912, me=0x0, recv=180469600)
    at vm_insnhelper.c:666
#27 0x00002b785397438c in vm_exec_core (th=0x8329020, initial=<value optimized out>) at insns.def:1006
#28 0x00002b7853979b99 in vm_exec (th=0xcce4c55) at vm.c:1147
#29 0x00002b7853970cd9 in invoke_block_from_c (th=0x8329020, block=0x2b78572ffa60, self=218506160, argc=1, argv=0x0, blockptr=0x0, cref=0x0)
    at vm.c:558
#30 0x00002b785397ad01 in rb_yield_0 (tag=30793742, data=<value optimized out>) at vm.c:588
#31 catch_i (tag=30793742, data=<value optimized out>) at vm_eval.c:1459
#32 0x00002b7853968483 in rb_catch_obj (tag=30793742, func=0x2b785397acc0 <catch_i>, data=0) at vm_eval.c:1534
#33 0x00002b785396978d in rb_f_catch (argc=<value optimized out>, argv=<value optimized out>) at vm_eval.c:1510
#34 0x00002b78539716aa in vm_call_cfunc (th=0x8329020, cfp=0x2b78572ffa38, num=1, blockptr=0x2b78572ffa61, flag=8, id=2840, me=0x83b2250, 
    recv=218506160) at vm_insnhelper.c:402
#35 vm_call_method (th=0x8329020, cfp=0x2b78572ffa38, num=1, blockptr=0x2b78572ffa61, flag=8, id=2840, me=0x83b2250, recv=218506160)
    at vm_insnhelper.c:524
#36 0x00002b785397438c in vm_exec_core (th=0x8329020, initial=<value optimized out>) at insns.def:1006
#37 0x00002b7853979b99 in vm_exec (th=0xcce4c55) at vm.c:1147
#38 0x00002b785396b4e5 in vm_call0 (th=0x8329020, recv=218506160, id=40296, argc=1, argv=0x7fff7bc685e0, me=0xd47b130) at vm_eval.c:66
#39 0x00002b785396bf9a in rb_call0 (recv=218506160, mid=40296, n=1) at vm_eval.c:235
#40 rb_call (recv=218506160, mid=40296, n=1) at vm_eval.c:438
#41 rb_funcall (recv=218506160, mid=40296, n=1) at vm_eval.c:638
#42 0x00002aaaac565bb6 in event_callback_wrapper (a1=<value optimized out>, a2=<value optimized out>, a3=<value optimized out>, 
    a4=<value optimized out>) at rubymain.cpp:162
#43 0x00002aaaac555688 in ConnectionDescriptor::_DispatchInboundData (this=0xca4a060, buffer=0x7fff7bc654e0 "\001", size=1402620608)
    at ed.cpp:770
#44 0x00002aaaac55571f in ConnectionDescriptor::Read (this=0xca4a060) at ed.cpp:718
#45 0x00002aaaac55e969 in EventMachine_t::_RunEpollOnce (this=0xc874530) at em.cpp:488
#46 0x00002aaaac55ec46 in EventMachine_t::_RunOnce (this=0xcce4c55) at em.cpp:451
#47 0x00002aaaac55ec93 in EventMachine_t::Run (this=0xc874530) at em.cpp:432
#48 0x00002aaaac565629 in t_run_machine_without_threads (self=214846549) at rubymain.cpp:185
#49 0x00002b78539716aa in vm_call_cfunc (th=0x8329020, cfp=0x2b78572ffbf0, num=0, blockptr=0x1, flag=24, id=39400, me=0x9055d80, 
    recv=139822160) at vm_insnhelper.c:402
#50 vm_call_method (th=0x8329020, cfp=0x2b78572ffbf0, num=0, blockptr=0x1, flag=24, id=39400, me=0x9055d80, recv=139822160)
    at vm_insnhelper.c:524
#51 0x00002b785397438c in vm_exec_core (th=0x8329020, initial=<value optimized out>) at insns.def:1006
#52 0x00002b7853979b99 in vm_exec (th=0xcce4c55) at vm.c:1147
#53 0x00002b7853979ff7 in rb_iseq_eval (iseqval=145595680) at vm.c:1374
#54 0x00002b785386d741 in rb_load_internal (fname=145597920, wrap=<value optimized out>) at load.c:294
#55 0x00002b785386d8a1 in rb_f_load (argc=<value optimized out>, argv=<value optimized out>) at load.c:367
#56 0x00002b78539716aa in vm_call_cfunc (th=0x8329020, cfp=0x2b78572fff08, num=1, blockptr=0x1, flag=8, id=5944, me=0x8421cd0, 
    recv=137928280) at vm_insnhelper.c:402
#57 vm_call_method (th=0x8329020, cfp=0x2b78572fff08, num=1, blockptr=0x1, flag=8, id=5944, me=0x8421cd0, recv=137928280)
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
    at vm_insnhelper.c:524
#58 0x00002b785397438c in vm_exec_core (th=0x8329020, initial=<value optimized out>) at insns.def:1006
#59 0x00002b7853979b99 in vm_exec (th=0xcce4c55) at vm.c:1147
#60 0x00002b7853979e74 in rb_iseq_eval_main (iseqval=145661040) at vm.c:1388
#61 0x00002b785386ae52 in ruby_exec_internal (n=0x8ae9c70) at eval.c:214
#62 0x00002b785386ae79 in ruby_exec_node (n=0x8ae9c70) at eval.c:261
#63 0x00002b785386d1bf in ruby_run_node (n=0x8ae9c70) at eval.c:254
#64 0x00000000004008ef in main (argc=10, argv=0x7fff7bc6df78) at main.c:35
```

What I can deduce from this:

- It's hanging on a regular expression performed on something like `52%%20off|utmcmd=email|utmctr=View%20this|utmcct=52%%20off`, which appears to be a bastardized form of a query string (any insights on why it's pipes rather than ampersands?). I don't know what the regex they're looking for is, though (any way I can find it?).
- It's getting through thin/eventmachine just fine to the rails stack just fine because at `#42`, it seems to be initializing an `event_callback_wrapper`, which I take to mean that it's handing it off to the next step in Rack.

And a weird thing:

- `netstat` doesn't list any outstanding connections, and `nginx` logs don't show any requests, successful, unsuccessful, or abandoned, with the query string implied by the string that shows up in the backtrace.

Other things I've tried:

I've tried just going into gdb and nexting a bunch of times, and it just goes in a loopish manner. I've also tried using [hijack](http://www.rubyinside.com/hijack-get-a-live-irb-prompt-for-any-existing-ruby-process-2232.html), but I couldn't find anything useful to do.

Things that might be useful that I don't know how to do or whether they are possible:

- Get an actual ruby code stack.
- Figure out what's calling the regex.
- Nailing down what the regex actually is and what it's being matched against.

Any other advice or whatnot would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think this one should go to ServerFault.

Comment: Not sure if it is of any help, but the string is probably not an URL, but the content of a Google Analytics tracking cookie: http://helpful.knobs-dials.com/index.php/Utma,_utmb,_utmz_cookies

Comment: @Mladen: great observation! I'll see what I can do with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the record, we just had and resolved that same issue (also using gdb, which was the only place we saw any indication of this). The problem is in lib/rack/backports/uri/common.rb, and varies depending on the version of Rack you're using. For the record, **we were using Rack 1.3.3, and migrated to 1.3.6 to correct it**.

In short, this catastrophic backtracking bug is part of Rack versions up to 1.3.3, and is properly fixed for both 1.8.7 and 1.9.2+ starting at Rack 1.3.4. The string the OP pasted above is the Google Analytics Cookie, and the campaign name in that cookie is "52% off", encoded here as "52%%20off". The solitary, unescaped "%" character in that string (in this, case, followed by the legal percent sign of a URI-encoded space, "%20") triggers a regex designed to catch malformed URI-escaped strings (paste into irb for best results).

```
/\A(?:%[0-9a-fA-F]{2}|[^%]+)*\z/
```

The embedded hunt for [^%]+ inside the (?:)* block drives your process to distraction, and the replacement appears to work much better:

```
/\A[^%]*(?:%\h\h[^%]*)*\z/
```

Important to note: The most catastrophic effect of this is on older Rack instances, which will hang and eat up all your CPU, bringing down your box. The "corrected" effect, in which the desired error is raised, can result in the simple failure of your user's request. Good for servers, bad for visitors. You can target specific strings in your cookies and scrub the adjacent percent signs in your Apache configuration as follows:

```
RequestHeader edit Cookie "%%" "Percent%"
```

That ought to be good enough.

Answer (score 1):

Let me guess: Rack 1.3.0? There's a [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) [regex bug](http://groups.google.com/group/rack-devel/browse_thread/thread/aadd3c25d9bada52) in that version. Upgrade to 1.3.1 or later.

Comment: Great job finding that! I didn't find anything like it. Unfortunately, I was rolling with Rack 1.3.2 the whole time.

Answer (score 0):

I wound up being unable to solve the problem. I finally figured out how to pull together a Ruby trace though and nailed down the stuck infinite loop to `lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/common.rb:778:in`decode_www_form_component'`.

I switched back to 1.8.7 and all was fine again.

Comment: Heh, that's actually the same regex bug. Rack contains a backport of `decode_www_form_component` for Ruby 1.8. I should've asked which version of Ruby you were using. :)